# Azure functions - slow performance when running a performance test

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have a function with some dependencies (two collections reads - cosmosDB, one storage read - blog storage in hot - and one cosmosDB write - ocasionally).

The functions runs well when alone, the reply is given in around 200 to 500ms. Most of these time is spent in IO and I use promises to avoid CPU lock while in IO.

I am making some performance testing with `Application Insights` using the 250 user load and duration of 10 minutes for a single URL (the same I am running with postman).

The results are pretty bad: 38s average response time, with 6.05 req/s.

I cant understand how a 200ms request can turn to be a 38s request with only 6 request per second. How this can be?

I filled the log with some info so I can see if some dependency is locking my function. The result of a 17s duration on application insights if the following:

```
28/11/2017 11:56:53 - Trace
Function completed (Success, Id=373364d5-4bd0-4f75-b526-2bd50067d98a, Duration=17228ms)
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:47 - Trace
Cliente já consultou esse item anteriormente
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:47 - Trace
Enviando dados do ativo para o cliente
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:46 - Trace
Validando dados do cliente
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:46 - Trace
Buscando pelo item procurado
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:45 - Trace
Buscando cliente na base de acessos diário do dia 
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:45 - Trace
Buscando cliente na base de clientes
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:45 - Trace
Obtendo informações 
Device type: PC
Severity level: Informational

28/11/2017 11:56:36 - Trace
Function started (Id=373364d5-4bd0-4f75-b526-2
```

As you can see by the log, from "function started" to my first log (which is the first line of the function), it spent 9 seconds. And from my latest log to "Function completed" it spent more 6 seconds. What is happening at those both moments and how can I avoid them?

As far as I understand, the problem is not related to the IO I make since the response times are reasonable between the logs).

Comment: put the code of your function, otherwise there's no way to help.

Comment: The code is proprietary... I was looking for some insight on why so much time is spent between "function started"  and my function properly start

Comment: Is your load test ramping up user load? Going from zero load to 250 concurrent requests instantaneously could result in this type of degenerate performance, depending on exactly what you're doing in your function. Also you might want to apply some limits to how many concurrent invocations of your function are permitted per instance - take a look here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#throttling

Comment: Hey Paul, that was a really good insight! Thank you very much. Setting a value to maxOutstandingRequests solved the problem (ok, we have a lot of 409 errors while the servers where going up).
Want to make a formal answer so I can approve it?